# why Mongodb create an empty document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The following code worked fined early, it suddenly stopped working and now I always add an empty document to my collection.

`{"_id":"5ccfca6bfbee8d4780d14cb0","__v":0,"product":[]}`

The only thing I get is:here is the model

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 var CartSchema = new Schema({
    product: [{

        productId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'product' },
        sku: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
        },

        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        brand: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        category: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },           
        quantity: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
          },
    }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Cart', CartSchema);
```

the function is as follows

```
 router.post('/',  function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body,"cart");
    Cart.create(req.body, function (err, cart) {
        if (err) {
                   return next(err);
        }      
        res.json(cart);
    });
  });
```

The req.body is as follows

```
{productId: '5cd82b7c8308f629fc376fa1', 
 sku: 'dddd6',
 name: 'G3 15 Gaming',
 brand: 'Dell',
 category: 'Laptop',
 quantity: 1 }
```

Comment: Can you show the `req.body`?

Comment: To be clear, it's **not** MongoDB doing this, but **Mongoose**. The reason **will be** that your content for the `product` array does not actually match the schema defined for the elements of that array, so mongoose will remove it. In fact its almost certainly because your actual `req.body` includes `products` as either a "string" ( being a JSON representation of an array ) or simply anything else which is ***not** an array*. Bottom line is your input for the POST will be incorrect and that is what you need fixed.

Comment: content of the product array matches the scheme

Comment: Your `req.body` is just one product, not an array of it.

Comment: not an array was the error. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 router.post('/',  function (req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.body);
       let cartInfo = new CartModel(req.body);
       cartInfo .save(function(err,succ){
          console.log("dddd====>>"+JSON.stringify(err))
          if(err){
            res.send({"responseCode":400,"responseMessage":"Cart  is already exist."})
          } else{            
            res.send({"responseCode":200,"responseMessage":"Cart information successfully added."})         
          }
          })
```

> Use .save fuction for save data .. .create function create a empty document.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add data inside an array

```
const product = {
    productId: '5cd82b7c8308f629fc376fa1', 
    sku: 'dddd6',
    name: 'G3 15 Gaming',
    brand: 'Dell',
    category: 'Laptop',
    quantity: 1 
};
```

You can use object with `save` method when cart `create`

```
Cart.create({ cartName: "testing" }, (error, cart) => {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }    
    cart.product.push(product);
    cart.save((error, saveCart) => {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }      
      res.json(saveCart);
  });
});
```

Or you can use

```
 Cart.create({ cartName: "testing", product: product }, (err, cart) => {
   if (err) {
     return next(err);
        }      
   res.json(cart);
});
```